# Exporting feature class from GDB into GeoPackage using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geopackage, error-000210

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.

I'm trying to export a feature class from an ESRI GDB into a GeoPackage using the following geoprocessing tools/methods, and all seem to fail:

1. Connect to SQLite (Geopackage) and Import the feature class from the GDB
2. Using the `Copy` or `Copy Features` from the 'Data Management' toolbox.

According to this article, it should be possible specifically with option #2:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/data-management/how-to-use-ogc-geopackages-in-arcgis-pro/

> Move your data into the GeoPackage like this:
> Create a GeoPackage with the Create SQLite Workspace tool (using the
> GeoPackage spatial type) Use the Copy tool (Data Management, General
> toolset) to add vector data Use the Add Raster to GeoPackage tool
> (Conversion, To GeoPackage toolset) to add raster mosaics

I'm able to export the data from the GDB as a shapefile, but running into encoding issues and thus I'd like to export as a GPKG (need to use it in QGIS for further analysis).

Does anyone know how to export a vector file into a GPKG in any other ways?

Here's the error I'm getting:

> ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:<username>\test.gpkg\test
> Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass)

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00201-00225-000210.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a test I used the Create SQLite Workspace to create a geopackage then I used Copy, Copy Features and FeatureClass to FeatureClass to move datasets into the geopackage. All of them worked without error. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9

So either its a bug in 2.7 or there is some sort of permission issue. Try creating your geopackage in a simple folder location like c:\temp.

Comment: It was indeed a bug with the earlier versions of ArcGIS Pro